# Would deleting messages from Facebook also delete them from my email?

Tags: facebook, email

If I delete messages from Facebook will it automatically delete from my email? Or do I have to delete both?

Comment: What kind of email do you mean? If you mean a non-Facebook email service, like Gmail, then no: Deleting a message on Facebook will not delete anything from Gmail. If you mean Facebook's [little-known @facebook.com email addresses](https://www.facebook.com/help/224049364288051), it could be different.

Answer (score 7):

No. Deleting message from Facebook only will delete from your Facebook inbox. To delete it from email you have to delete separately.